# Is there a way to configure Apache to auto-recognize URLs for Django vs React without hard-coding each endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, apache, apache-config

We're using Apache 2.4 with React 17 and a Django 3.2 (Python 3.9) application.  Curious about a better way to set up our Apache configs to route requests to the React and Django apps.  Right now, our Apache virtual hosts file hard-codes which routes need to be handled by the React app vs which need to be handled by Django ...

```
    AliasMatch ^/(?!people)(?!states/)(?!countries/)(?!predefined_types/)(?!coop_types/)(?!coops/)(?!data)(?!save_to_sheet_from_form).* /var/www/html/client/build/$0

    <Directory "/var/www/html/client/build/">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess ssl_directory home=/var/www/html/web python-home=/var/www/html/web/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /coops /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/coops process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /data /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/data process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /countries /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/countries process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /states /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/states process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /predefined_types /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/predefined_types process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /coop_types /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/coop_types process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /people /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/people process-group=ssl_directory
    WSGIScriptAlias /save_to_sheet_from_form /var/www/html/web/directory/wsgi.py/save_to_sheet_from_form process-group=ssl_directory
```

The Django app, for its part, defines urls in the standard way (in our urls.py file) ...

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('data', views.data, name='data'),
    path('coops/no_coords', views.coops_wo_coordinates, name='coops_wo_coordinates'),
    path('coops/unapproved', views.unapproved_coops, name='unapproved_coops'),
    path('coops/', views.CoopList.as_view()),
    path('coops/<int:pk>/', views.CoopDetail.as_view()),
    path('people/', views.PersonList.as_view()),
    path('people/<int:pk>/', views.PersonDetail.as_view()),
    path('users/', views.CreateUserView.as_view()),
    path('predefined_types/', views.CoopTypeList.as_view()),
    path('coop_types/', views.CoopTypeList.as_view()),
    path('countries/', views.CountryList.as_view()),
    path('states/<country_code>', views.StateList.as_view()),
    path('login', views.signin),
    path(settings.LOGOUT_PATH, views.signout),
    path('user_info', views.user_info),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Is there a more automated way we can get Apache to know what routes shoudl go to Django vs React?  Whenever we add a new Django endpoint, we have to add a hard-coded exception in our Apache configs.

**Edit:** Here is an example how I make a React call to the API ...

```
const { REACT_APP_PROXY } = process.env;

class PersonService {
  getById(id, callback) {
    fetch(REACT_APP_PROXY + "/people/" + id)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const person = data;
        person.contact_methods.map((contact_method) => {
          if (contact_method.type == "PHONE") {
            person.phone = contact_method.phone.substring(2);
          } else if (contact_method.type == "EMAIL") {
            person.email = contact_method.email;
          }
        });
        if (callback) callback(person);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Concerning python there are two wsgi-options that could help you to reduce the required lines and steps.

1. Using the WSGIScriptAlias directive to map to a directory containing
   any number of WSGI applications:

   ```
   WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/
   ```

   When this is used, the next part of the URL after the URL prefix is
   used to identify which WSGI application script file within the target
   directory should be used. Both the mount point and the directory path
   must have a trailing slash.
2. Another option is intended primarily to suppress the extension in the
   Frontend but could be used too to redirect based on different aspects:

   ```
   WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/wsgi/([^/]+) /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/$1.wsgi
   ```

   In this case, any path information appearing after the URL prefix, will be mapped to a corresponding WSGI script file in the directory, but with a ‘.wsgi’ extension. The extension would though not need to be included in the URL.

The options can be configured with common Apache directives too, and there are additional features like directory index can be configured like that, it's useful to read this page about all the options: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html

Furthermore you've the option to use the powerful [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Certainly there are many more options, most important is that to distinguish between script-types you've to have some aspect in the url or path to decide where to redirect. It can be a suffix and / or usage of WSGIScriptAlias which both would be most simple but could be based on [mod_mime](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) perhaps too.

So actually the question in return is how far you're willing to use suffixes or URLs that make a distinction possible and easy enough to be handled by the offered options.

One aspect to consider is that a python app can reference js-files too, so simply a suffix might not be enough but if full paths are provided that's perhaps not too difficult to handle.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what changes I would need to make -- you have "WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ ..." -- does that mean any URL hitting Apache with "/wsgi/" would get routed to Python for processing?

Comment: yes,  that's how I understood thee documentation.
I propose to test it, and also take care if JavaScript files referenced by the python scripts behave correctly.

Comment: This would involve going into my React app, changing all the endpoints to include /wsgi/ and then altering the Django urls file to prefix all URLs with /wsgi, if I'm following.  Not that I'm against taht, but I was kind of hoping for something that might work with what I already have, but that might be a pipe dream on my part.

Comment: If you've clearly separated aspects for the react app, there is no need to change the path probably. You could likely combine different methods by nifty orders in the ".htaccess" file (or different server configuration).

Comment: I added an example of how we currently make calls from React to the API endpoints -- basically they are all fetch calls using a REACT_APP_PROXY constant.  Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: you'd need some outstanding aspect in the path in comparison to the wsgi routes. Then you could redirect first to the react app if applying and afterwards to the right wsgi project. If you've only on react app, you can just use the full project path, else you'd need a common path segment for all react apps.

Comment: ANother logic would be to redirect everything with "/wsgi/" in the path to the python route and the rest to the react route

Comment: Is "process.env" a value or still a variable? I think it's not a real path,  is it?

Comment: based on your code I think the path part "/people/" would be typical for the react app, you had to filter wsgi first because there could be a site ".../people/..." too but the ".../.wsgi/.." part is unique for the python stuff

Answer (score 0):

With `mod_rewrite` you have full control over redirection and remapping in Apache

[Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html)

You should implement something like this:

```
RedirectMatch "^/docs/(.*)" "http://new.example.com/docs/$1"
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ /assets/images/public/$1 [L]
```

That redirects each part of application documents to its corresponding handler.

```
RedirectMatch "^/react-docs/(.*)" "http://react-handler.example.com/react-docs/$1"
```

As you see you need something in your URL that `RedirectMatch` or `RewriteRule` uses Regex on it for separating and sending each document to corresponding handler.

[Q&As on mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite)

Comment: I don't see how this saves me any time.  What you're sugesting is I transfer the directives I've made in my virtual configuration file to an .htaccess file.  My goal is that every time I add a new endpoint into my Python app, I don't have to hard-code some kind of special logic somewhere.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're suggesting.

Comment: Additional explanation added to answer